# Perform query with join and comma separated values in column in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have table `orders` which has column files. The column holds file id's and they are comma separated.

Second table is `documents`.

Table Name : orders

```
 orders_id | order_details | file_id
 ------------------------------------
     1     | some details  |   1,2
```

Table Name : documents

```
 id |   name 
 ------------------
  1 | file name
  2 | file2 name2
```

Currently I have this query which query only `orders` table but I want to join documents also so I can show to customer the names of documents which are connected in `file_id` column in `orders`

```
$docomuntOrders = Order::where('user_id',getCurrentUser()->user_id)
                        ->orderBy('order_id', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Can you guide a little bit here?

Comment: You should use `order_id` in the documents table to define relationship If it's is in development phase. Other wise `json`  can be another good option

Comment: But `documents` is separated table. When I upload documents via admin panel is stored there. I don't know `order_id` and I should not need to know it. I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: You can use `array_map` to get file_id of one column but with all it will be difficult to get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope It will work for you. have a try

```
$docomuntOrders = \DB::table("orders")
            ->select("orders.*",\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(documents.name) as docname"))
            ->leftjoin("documents",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(documents.id,orders.file_id)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
            ->where('user_id',getCurrentUser()->user_id)
            ->groupBy("orders.id")
            ->paginate(10);
```

if you try it `dd($docomuntOrders)` hope it will return desired result.

Comment: Quick question: How to select then document_name for example? when I do `@foreach($downloadableOrders as $download) { $download->document_name }` i got NULL

Comment: @user5996816 i update my answer and i think its ready for you :)

Comment: `int(87)` which is correct id for the user I'm currently logged in

Comment: Also I can see it in `dd($docomuntOrders)` but when I remove `dd($docomuntOrders)` and tried to load the page got the error above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149478/discussion-between-blue-moon-and-user5996816).

Comment: Yes, huge output but when i search trough I can see the values. When I remove `dd(...)` nothing shown. Maybe I didn't accessing them correctly. How to access variables now?

Comment: Hi, what does mean this please ? `">",\DB::raw("'0'"`

Answer (score 0):

**A single user has multiple company and company id's are in users table in a single filed with comma separation. In that case this is the solution, which is very similar to your problem.**

```
Users::leftJoin("company_info as ci",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(ci.id,users.company_ids)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get([
        'users.*',
        \DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(ci.company_name) as company_name")
    ]);
```